# Como pegar dados de um relacionamento N para N

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho uma tabela tb_produtos com idproduto, desproduct, outra tabela tb_categorias com idcategory, descategory, e por fim uma ultima tabela product_category com idproduct e idcategory.

Se eu quiser, por exemplo, pegar todos os produtos que tem como idcategory 1 como eu faria essa busca usando tambem a tabela product_category? Eu tenho muito essa duvida de como pegar dados de tabelas com relacionamento N para N

Answer (score 2):

Você pode construir a consulta de diversas formas, pois os JOINS entre tabelas tem N possibilidades. Mas uma das formas seria:

```
SELECT pc.*,pro.desproduct,cat.descategory from tb_produtos as pro
INNER JOIN product_category AS pc ON pc.idproduto = pro.idproduto
INNER JOIN tb_categorias  AS cat ON pc.idcategory = cat.idcategory
```

***OBS***: utilizando inner join o ids não podem ser nulos

## Ex:

## **tb_produtos**

idproduto  | desproduct

```
1            ABC
2            XYZ
```

## **tb_categorias**

idproduto  | descategory

```
1         categoria1
2         categoria2
```

## **product_category**

idproduto  | idcategory

```
1           1
1           2
2           1
```

**Ao executar a consulta mencionada o resultado seria**

idproduto  | idcategory | desproduct | descategory

```
 1           1             ABC      categoria1
 1           2             ABC      categoria2
 2           1             XYZ      categoria1
```

O produto 1 pertence a categoria 1 e 2 e o produto 2 pertence a
categoria 1.